# How to access report parameters array in fusion spreadsheet

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-fusion-sheet

Parameters have been enabled to interact between spreadsheet and report: If parameter set in report it is accessible through linked cell.

However this works for just one single value for [string] parameter.

If multiple values entered in report form mentioned cell in spreadsheet appears empty and filtered lookups depending on this do not work any more.

-> How may I set up lookup() function in spreadsheet to work with multiple values for report parameters?

-> How to access multiple values for report parameter in spreadsheet

Thanks in advance.